# Handling HRESULTs in a Direct2D application

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d, hresult

In Kenny Kerr's msdn magazine articles on imaging and Direct2D he frequently uses `HR()` macro.

In his Windows Imaging Component article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc500647.aspx

he writes -

> Finally, the WIC API makes use of HRESULTs to describe errors. The samples in this article use the HR macro to clearly identify where methods return an HRESULT that needs to be checked. You can replace this with your own error-handling strategy—whether that is throwing an exception or returning the HRESULT yourself.

```
HR(decoder.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICTiffDecoder));
```

However Kenny doesn't show his definition of `HR()`. I am a C++ beginner and am trying to discover and understand the details of the code. I would like to know what his implementation of `HR()` is so that I can consider how best to handle the `HRESULT` in my program. I have searched to find a definition but there doesn't appear to be source code for these particular articles.

Whilst learning about `macros` I have come across these more recent documents that propose the use of `inline` functions instead of macros -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttsbh614.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z8y1yy88.aspx

Can anybody tell me how Kenny defines his `HR()` macro? And what it actually does?

How should my Direct2D program handle `HRESULT`s? What is the way to make proper use of `HRESULT`s so that the program is reliable and resilient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure about Kenny's macros, however I suppose that you absolutely need to know the following: error codes have most significant bit set and render the whole value negative. "Standard" macros `SUCCEEDED` and `FAILED` test codes exactly for this.

```
HRESULT nValue = ...
if(SUCCEEDED(nValue)) {
  // Not Error
}
```

Then for code brevity and readability you will want a macro that does both things together: tests for success/failure and either returns on error, or throws an exception. I suppose `HR` macro in question does one of the two.

If you are going to use ATL, there are predefined macros of this kind already: `ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED`, `ATLENSURE_THROW` etc. Microsoft decided to not document them though (I am not aware of a MSDN link to provide here).

Your `HR` could be something like (depending on desired action - to throw or exit on error):

```
inline VOID HR(HRESULT nValue) { if(FAILED(nValue)) AtlThrow(nValue); }
```

or

```
#define HR(x) { HRESULT nValue = (x); if(FAILED(nValue)) return nValue; }
```

Also, to conveniently decode WIC and D2D `HRESULT`s you might want to use this [system tray helper app](http://alax.info/blog/1383).

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN article from Kenny may assist others understanding possible approaches for error handling, including throwing exceptions: [MSDN - C++ and the Windows API July 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288076.aspx)